# On click on the submenu need to add route and avoid wait to load the details

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a web application and logged into that. On the Menu > Submenu I have a 'Customers' link. When I click on the customers link there is some delay in loading the page
Can we add a `cy.route()` for that ? The below route is not working. For the time being I am using cy.wait() an need to avoid that.

I am getting an error >> Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: getCustomers. No request ever occurred.

```
context('Route testing', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.loginToWebApplication();
  });

  it('Test route', () => {
    cy.server();
    cy.route({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://testsite-url/company/customers.php',
    }).as('getCustomers');
    cy.get('#submenu_People ul li a')
      .contains('Customers')
      .click({force: true});
    cy.get('input[name="searchText"]').type('Some Customer');
    cy.wait('@getCustomers');
  });
});
```

Another example, one on click on the Search button, some delay in navigating and displaying the invoice data: In both cases routes are not working, could someone please give some idea.

```
it('Test route', () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url:
      '**invoices.php?&ajaxCall=true&selectedMainItem=invoices&invoiceItem=unpaid**',
  }).as('invoicesSearch');
  cy.get('#Invoices ul li a').contains('Current Invoices').click({force: true});
  cy.get('#resultsTable tbody tr').each(($tr, index) => {
    const invoiceID = Cypress.$($tr).find('td').eq(1).text();
    if (invoiceID == 1280) {
      cy.get('#searchText').type(invoiceID);
    }
  });
  cy.get('.searchContainer button[type="button"]')
    .contains('Search')
    .click({force: true});
  cy.wait('@invoicesSearch');
  cy.get('#invoicesSearch h2').contains('Current Invoices (1)');
});
```

Comment: If native fetch is used by the app, cy.route() won't catch it. You can try the [Experimental Fetch Polyfill](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/29/experimental-fetch-polyfill/).

Comment: Oh ok great  ! I will try that and reply shortly. Not sure if native fetch calls being used.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous examples in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app) of watching routes and waiting for results before proceeding with the test, which is a best practice.

Refer to our [transaction feeds spec](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/tests/ui/transaction-feeds.spec.ts#L46) and it's `beforeEach` block where we recommend placing `cy.server` and `cy.route` statements.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried adding route in beforeEach() but still I am getting Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: invoicesSearch No request ever occurred.